# Clicking on data point returns "There has been an error..."

Tags: carto

My CartoDB map has different data shown for hovering and clicking. It works fine when I'm logged in, but other folks can't see the clicking data. CartoDB thinks for a few seconds, then returns "There has been an error..."

I'm doing this map totally with the GUI, not programming anything directly. The map has two layers, one of county population and the other of about 5000 schools, and it's the latter that's the problem.

Comment: Could you share the link? So, we could check that error. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The "No data available" errors are usually provoked by a user accessing the map from an internet connection which is behind a proxy/firewall.

In this case, I recommend you to access your map through HTTPS instead of HTTP, so when you share the URL for your map make sure to include https at the beginning. For example: https://team.cartodb.com/u/hayleyrichardson/viz/8e84c27a-d6e3-11e4-a823-0e853d047bba/public_map